# How to find list of customers pending dues from their payment table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having 3 tables in mysql database like customers,customeraccount,customerpayment

Customers table structure

```
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| cusid    | cusname    | cusmobileno   | cusaddress    |
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1        |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx |   XXXXXX      |
| 2        |  XXXX-B    |    xxxxxxxxxx |   XXXXXX      |
| 3        |  XXXX-C    |    xxxxxxxxxx |   XXXXXX      |
| 4        |  XXXX-D    |    xxxxxxxxxx |   XXXXXX      |
| 5        |  XXXX-E    |    xxxxxxxxxx |   XXXXXX      |
| 6        |  XXXX-F    |    xxxxxxxxxx |   XXXXXX      |
| 7        |  XXXX-G    |    xxxxxxxxxx |   XXXXXX      |
+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Customeraccount table structure

```
    +----------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
    | cusid    | accno      | acc_Create_Date | acc_type    |
    +----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
    | 1        |  0000-1    |    2014-01-05 |        0      |
    | 1        |  0000-2    |    2014-01-15 |        0      |
    | 2        |  0000-3    |    2014-01-15 |        1      |
    | 3        |  0000-4    |    2014-01-15 |        0      |
    | 4        |  0000-5    |    2014-01-16 |        0      |
    | 5        |  0000-6    |    2014-01-15 |        1      |
    | 5        |  0000-7    |    2014-02-05 |        1      |
    | 6        |  0000-8    |    2014-02-07 |        0      |
    +----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Customerpayment table structure

```
        +----------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
        | cpcusid  | cp_accno   | cp_paydate    |   cp_amount   |
        +----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
        | 1        |  0000-1    |    2014-01-05 |        5000   |
        | 1        |  0000-2    |    2014-01-15 |        7000   |
        | 2        |  0000-3    |    2014-01-15 |        4000   |
        | 3        |  0000-4    |    2014-01-15 |        8000   |
        | 4        |  0000-5    |    2014-01-16 |        9000   |
        | 5        |  0000-6    |    2014-01-15 |        6000   |
        | 1        |  0000-1    |    2014-02-05 |        5000   | 
        | 5        |  0000-7    |    2014-02-05 |        9000   |
        | 6        |  0000-8    |    2014-02-07 |        5000   |
        | 1        |  0000-2    |    2014-02-17 |        7000   | 
        | 2        |  0000-3    |    2014-02-15 |        4000   |
        | 3        |  0000-4    |    2014-02-17 |        8000   |
        | 1        |  0000-1    |    2014-03-02 |        5000   |
        +----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

From these tables i need to show the list of customers pending payments for every month like bellow table(I'm expecting result)
Will calculate for current date from account created date

```
    +-------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
    | CId   | Name       |     Phone     |   Address |   Accnumber | DueMonth  |
    +-------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
    | 4     |  XXXX-D    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-5   |  2014/02  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-2   |  2014/03  |
    | 2     |  XXXX-B    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-3   |  2014/03  |
    | 3     |  XXXX-C    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-4   |  2014/03  |
    | 4     |  XXXX-D    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-5   |  2014/03  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-1   |  2014/04  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-2   |  2014/04  |
    | 2     |  XXXX-B    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-3   |  2014/04  |
    | 3     |  XXXX-C    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-4   |  2014/04  |
    | 4     |  XXXX-D    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-5   |  2014/04  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-1   |  2014/05  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-2   |  2014/05  |
    | 2     |  XXXX-B    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-3   |  2014/05  | 
    | 3     |  XXXX-C    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-4   |  2014/05  |
    | 4     |  XXXX-D    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-5   |  2014/05  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-1   |  2014/06  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-2   |  2014/06  |
    | 2     |  XXXX-B    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-3   |  2014/06  |
    | 3     |  XXXX-C    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-4   |  2014/06  |
    | 4     |  XXXX-D    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-5   |  2014/06  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-1   |  2014/07  |
    | 1     |  XXXX-A    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-2   |  2014/07  |
    | 2     |  XXXX-B    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-3   |  2014/07  |
    | 3     |  XXXX-C    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-4   |  2014/07  |
    | 4     |  XXXX-D    |    xxxxxxxxxx | XXXXXXXX  |    0000-5   |  2014/07  |
    +-------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Payments will pay monthly scheme, so date should be get from customeraccount table acc_create_date field.
For example if customer account is created on 2014-06-25 then if i see the report on 2014-07-24 it should not show it is a pending payment and if i see the report on 2014-07-26 it should show as pending payment.

Please any one help me to get above result.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: it is reference of customer table cusid

Comment: I have tried like this.It will give exact result for total count of dues. SELECT
cus_id,cus_firstname,cus_mobile,cus_address,ca_cusaccnumber,
sum(((SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, ca_createdtime, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))+1) -
(SELECT count(*) FROM chf_customerpayments WHERE cp_cusaccno = ca_cusaccnumber))) as previousdues
FROM chf_customeraccount
LEFT JOIN chf_customers ON cus_id = ca_cusaccid
WHERE ca_accountstatus=1 AND ca_cusaccounttype=0
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, ca_createdtime, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) > 0
Group by ca_cusaccnumber

Comment: So customers can pay each other's accounts?

Comment: No they can pay for their account only. Customer can have multiple account.and they will do payment for their multiple account for every month of their due date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this PHP+MYSQLi Code, (MySQL queries are tested but not PHP-you can do it by your own)

```
$result=mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT min(date) FROM customeraccount;");
if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ $minDate=date_create(row[0]); }

$currDate=date_create();

while($currDate>date_add($minDate,date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 month'))){
      $result=mysqli_query($dbCon,"select ca.cusid,ca.accno,c.cusname,c.cusmobileno,c.cusaddress from customerpayment cp right join customeraccount ca on ca.accno=cp.cp_accno and year('$minDate')=year(cp.cp_paydate) and month('$minDate')=month(cp.cp_paydate) left join customers c on ca.cusid=c.cusid where month('$minDate')>=month(ca.acc_create_date) and year('$minDate')>=year(ca.acc_create_date) and cp.cpcusid is null;");
      echo "<table>";
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           echo "<tr><td>".join($row,"</td><td>")."</td><td>".date_format($minDate,"Y/m")."</td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
}
```